# Overflow in modal popup

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an overflow in the modal popup.The overflow should only be for horizontal scrolling. But the text crosses the height of the pop up modal. 
Heres the link to codepen 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AKqJf

CSS:

```
html,body {margin:0; padding:10px; -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;}
img {width:100%;}
/* text-based popup styling */
.white-popup {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 25px;
  width:auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  margin: 0 auto; 

}





/* 

====== Zoom effect ======

*/
.zoom-in {

  /* start state */
  .anim {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
    transform: scale(0.8); 
  }

  &.mfp-bg {
    opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  }

  /* animate in */
  &.mfp-ready {
    .anim {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: scale(1); 
    }
    &.mfp-bg {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
  }

  /* animate out */
  &.mfp-removing {

    .anim {
      transform: scale(0.8); 
      opacity: 0;
    }
    &.mfp-bg {
      opacity: 0;
    }

  }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: Basically what Im trying to create is a modal popup with vertical overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't completely get your question but check this

```
.white-popup {
position: relative;
background: #FFF;
padding: 25px;
width:auto;
max-width: 400px;
height: 100px;
overflow-y:scroll;
margin-top:100px; 
}
```